# dimple.js filter data by legend gives error

Tags: d3.js, legend, dimple.js

I'm using a dimple bar chart legend to filter the chart's data as given in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fbpnzy9u/.

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
var data = [
    { Animal: "Cats", Value: (Math.random() * 1000000) },
    { Animal: "Dogs", Value: (Math.random() * 1000000) },
    { Animal: "Mice", Value: (Math.random() * 1000000) }
];

var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 510, 305)
var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Animal");
x.addOrderRule(["Cats", "Dogs", "Mice"]);
myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Value");
myChart.addSeries("Animal", dimple.plot.bar);
var legend = myChart.addLegend(500,10,100, 100, "right");
myChart.draw();

d3.select("#btn").on("click", function() {
   myChart.data = [
     { Animal: "Cats", Value: (Math.random() * 1000000) },
     { Animal: "Dogs", Value: (Math.random() * 1000000) },
     { Animal: "Mice", Value: (Math.random() * 1000000) }
   ];
   myChart.draw(1000);
});

// filter
    myChart.legends = [];

    // Get a unique list of y values to use when filtering
    var filterValues = dimple.getUniqueValues(data, "Animal");

    // Get all the rectangles from our now orphaned legend

    legend.shapes.selectAll('rect').on("click", function (e) {

    // This indicates whether the item is already visible or not
    var hide = false;
    var newFilters = [];
    //If the filters contain the clicked shape hide it

    filterValues.forEach(function (f) {
      if (f === e.aggField.slice(-1)[0]) {
        hide = true;
      } else {
        newFilters.push(f);
      }
    });

    if (hide) {
        d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0.2);
    } else {
      newFilters.push(e.aggField.slice(-1)[0]);
      d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0.8);
    }
    // // Update the filters
    filterValues = newFilters;
    //Filter the data
    myChart.data = dimple.filterData(data, "Animal", filterValues);
    myChart.draw(800);
});
```

Although the filtering happens as expected, it throws a d3 error on to the console:
Error:  attribute x: Expected length, "NaN"

Any idea as to what may be causing this error?

Comment: Emma, look like that probably only shows up with google chrome. When I tried with IE, I didn't had that error showing in console.

Comment: I'll look that up. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Did you figured out what really cause that issue? if you did please share with us. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately no, dimplejs seems not maintained anymore. The same issue i raised with d3 got reviewed and they said its an issue with dimple

Comment: @Emma would you mind linking that issue? If someone could figure this one out, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what might be causing the error.

What my intuition tells me is that since the shapes from the previous set of data are being accessed when the chart is being redrawn with the new data since they're separate objects in memory. That is, the data generates the series which lives in the chart's svg object but is in no way tied to changes of the data until a chart is redrawn. If this is true, that could be why it's not finding values for the axes in order to draw the shapes that live there. (I wonder if there's a fail silently option in the future).

Anyway, if you are redrawing the chart, you could do this workaround:

```
if (oldChartData.length > newChartData.length) {
    chart.svg.selectAll('*').remove();
    createChart(newChartData);
}
```

It's dirty but it works.

Edit: [Here's](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/issues/248) the related github issue.